# Загрузка картинки из html в ASP.NET core

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

Не получается отправить файл из HTML в ASP.NET Core

Код на стороне HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/file-upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Код на стороне бэкенда

```
 [Route("file-upload")]
 [ApiController]
 public class TodoItemsController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public void OnPostUpload(List<IFormFile> uploadedFile)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("POST дошел до бэка!");
            Console.WriteLine(uploadedFile.Count);
        }
    }
```

И вот я запускаю билд, он загружается, выводит консоль, и открывается HTML страничка с кнопкой выбора файла(нажимаем, выбираем файл) и с кнопкой Upload Image(Нажимаем кнопку)

И в консоли видим следующее

POST дошел до бэка!

0

Что означает что метод мы вызвали, но в аргументах пришел пустой лист. Почему? Что я делаю не так?

Comment: [Загрузка файлов на сервер](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/21.3.php)

Comment: @tym32167 Благодарю вас! Видел этот туториал, но в нем идет работа с cshtml файлами, а не просто с html, так что он не совсем подходит. Я хотел сделать что то минимально работающее, загружаем файл с HTML страницы, принимаем его на C# бэкенде.

Comment: 1) делаете этот пример по ссылке 2) Смотрите, какая разметка сгенерировалась 3) Используете эту разметку.

Comment: Покажите код IFormFile

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поместить эту конструкцию внутрь метода контроллера:

```
Console.WriteLine(Request.Form.Files.Count);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните свой ответ: зачем это делать ТС и к чему это приведет.

Comment: Дело в том, что это другой способ получения файлов, у меня тоже не работал Ваш способ.В данном случае вы получите количество файлов в запросе.Request.Form.Files - коллекция файлов в вашем запросе к серверу. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfilecollection?view=aspnetcore-3.1